# CPT output on page breaks other fields

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

Not sure what i have done wrong here but i noticed that everything dissapears below my code.
If i take fields and put them in top of template then everything works fine.

Code

```
    <?php
    $blacklabelpost = array( 'post_type' => 'black-label', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $blacklabelpost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
        $images = get_field('photos_of_product'); // get gallery
        $image  = $images[0]; // get first image in the gallery [1] for second, [2] for third, and so on.

        if( $image ) : // only show the image if it exists ?> 
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product-col">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3 class="UC sTitle"><?php the_title()?></h3>
                        <div class="border-line center"></div>
                        <div class="subtitle about_product_short UC"><?php the_field('about_product_short'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="UC read-more">Läs mer</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Below i just have couple of **if get field**.
Example

```
<?php if( get_field('full_width_photo_footer') ): ?>
    <div class="F-W sida archive">
        <?php 
        $image = get_field('full_width_photo_footer');

        if( !empty($image) ): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="img-responsive footer-fullwidth-img"/>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As soon as i delete this 'full_width_photo_footer' starts to work again:

```
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'white-label', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: So, wait, what's wrong with your code? What's happening?

Comment: Hello. Just edited with a bit better explanation of codes.
Can't figure out where i am doing wrong so that one of ACF fields doesnt appear.

Comment: Are you using the custom field plugin becauase you uses the code like `get_field('full_width_photo_footer')`?